# Notify change of angular service in function when function defined as property

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I've written a cool function in angular-ui [ui-grid](http://ui-grid.info/) which applies a dynamic class to rows in the column, depending on the value in that column. I am 98.5% done, but in software that last 1.5% is always the most frustrating. This is for reports of sent emails, where we want messages with 75% open rates to be colored green, and ones with 1% open rates to be colored red, the middle values yellow. This I've already achieved through a cellClass function, which essentially compares the row value to the rest of the rows in the column and then gives it a css class.

```
    cellClass: function(grid, row, col, rowRenderIndex, colRenderIndex) {
      var getColorGroup = function(array, element){
        var colorArray = ["63BE7B", "72C27B", "82C77C", "91CB7D", "A1D07E", "B1D47F", "C0D980", "D0DD81", "DFE282", "EFE683", "FFEB84", "FFDE82", "FED280", "FDC47D", "FDB87B", "FCAA78", "FB9D75", "FB9073", "FA8370", "F9776E", "F8696B"],
            max = Math.max.apply(Math, array),
            min = Math.min.apply(Math, array),
            range = max - min,
            numRows = array.length,
            stepValue = range / 100,
            percent = Math.floor((parseFloat(element) - min) / stepValue),
            color = Math.floor(percent / 100 * (colorArray.length - 1));
        return color;
      };

      var getColumnVals = function(array, column){
        var columnArr = [];
        for(var i = 0, _len = array.length; i < _len; i++){
          columnArr.push(parseFloat(array[i][column]));
        }
        return columnArr;
      };

      var thisRow = grid.getCellValue(row, col);
      //return 'group' + thisRow;
      var asdf = getColumnVals($scope.gridOptions.data, this.name); // "name"
      var qwer = getColorGroup(asdf, thisRow);

      console.log(this.name + " is colored? " + this.isColored); // + coloredColService[this.name] );
      if(coloredColService[this.name]){ //(this.isColored){ 
        return 'group' +  qwer;
      }
    }
```

above, I am expecting this.isColored to go up one level. $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs is an array of POJOs, and i'd expect `this` to refer to the JSON object in that array, which contains the cellClass property/function. I know `this` is referring to the because I am logging `this.name`. For some reason it isn't seeing this.isColored, so I'm using a service `coloredColService`

I have a [plunkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/hRrpvBpZd4H8xDLB38ea?p=preview)

My goal is to be able to toggle this cellClass in the column Menu.

```
  menuItems: [
    {
        icon: 'ui-grid-icon-ok',
        title: "Toggle Color",
        action: function(){ 
          alert(this.context.col.colDef.name + " is " + $scope.coloredCols[this.context.col.colDef.name]);
          $scope.coloredCols[this.context.col.colDef.name] = !$scope.coloredCols[this.context.col.colDef.name];
        }
    }],
```

above is the general idea.

The main issue here is that the styles won't go away - even with the alerts confirming I am successfully changing the value to false. **the `if` statement which checks if the column is supposed to be colored, but isn't watching the service for changes**. I have used $scope.watch before, but I don't think I can do that from within the function as it is defined as a property in the columnDefs

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/2598

Comment: $scope.gridApi.core.notifyDataChange($scope.gridApi.grid, uiGridConstants.dataChange.COLUMN);